# No manda los valores correctos

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web

Estoy tratando de hacer el Algoritmo por el método congruencial multiplicativo, el cuales el siguiente

```
El algoritmo congruencial m ultiplicativo surge del algoritmo congruencial lineal cuando
c = 0. Entonces la ecuación recursiva es:
XM = {aX) mod (m) i = 0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,...,n
```

Pero al ingresar los valores me manda todo en cero. ejemplo si ingreso
X0 = 17, k = 2 y g = 5
me deberia mandar el siguiente resultado

```
Solución:
a = 5 + 8 (2) = 21 y m = 32
X0= 17
X, =(21*17) mod 32 = 5 r, =5/31 =0.612
X2 = (21*5) mod 32 = 9 r2 = 9/31 = 0.2903
X3 = (21 *9) mod 32 = 29 r3 = 29/31 = 1.9354
X4 = (21*29) mod 32 = 1 r4 = 1/31 =0.3225
X5 =(21*1) mod 32 = 21 r5 = 21/31 = 0.6774
X6 = (21*21) mod 32 = 2 5 r6 = 25/31 = 0.8064
X? = (21*25) mod 32 = 13 r?= 13/31 = 0.4193
X8 = (21*13) mod 32 = 17 r8= 17/31 = 0.5483
```

Este es mi codigo

```js
    function generar() {
  var semilla = parseInt(document.getElementById("semillas").value);
  var constante = parseInt(document.getElementById("k").value);
  var modulo = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);
  var cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);

  // Verificar condiciones necesarias
  if (modulo % 2 !== 0 && (constante === 3 || constante === 5 || constante % 8 === 3 || constante % 8 === 5)) {
    var numeros = [];
    var x = semilla;

    // Crear tabla
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var headerRow = table.insertRow();
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("i"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("X[i]"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("número generado"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("r"));

    for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
      var numero = (constante * x) % modulo;
      var r = numero / (modulo - 1);

      numeros.push(numero);

      // Insertar fila en la tabla
      var row = table.insertRow();
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(numero));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.toFixed(4)));

      x = numero;
    }

    // Agregar tabla al documento
    var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    resultado.innerHTML = "";
    resultado.appendChild(table);
  } else {
    alert("Los valores ingresados para los parámetros no cumplen las condiciones necesarias para alcanzar el período máximo.");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Congruencial Multiplicativo</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="semilla">Semilla inicial:</label>
        <input type="text" id="semillas" name="semillas"><br>

        <label for="k">k</label>
        <input type="text" id="k" name="k"><br>

        <label for="g">g:</label>
        <input type="text" id="g" name="g"><br>

        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de números:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="10"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="generar()">Generar</button>
    </form>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
  </body>
```

En este momento me manda puros valores de NaN, me hace bien la interaccion pero al momento de crear el modulo, lo emplea mal y manda a 0.
Intente de varias formas y segun yo lo estoy implementando bien, pero me sigue mandando valores nulos
De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Hola El Chido, ingresando semilla = 17, k = 5 y g = 3, me devuelve i X[i] número generado r
1 17 1 0.5000
2 1 2 1.0000
3 2 1 0.5000
4 1 2 1.0000
5 2 1 0.5000
6 1 2 1.0000
7 2 1 0.5000
8 1 2 1.0000
9 2 1 0.5000
10 1 2 1.0000

Comment: Yo lo probé con estos número y me da los mismos valores: https://naps.com.mx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/algoritmo-congruencial-multiplicativo-java.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variables de la fórmula estaban mal asignadas, mejore la recursividad y elimine un append que no le vi la utilidad.

Edit: Hay otra página que ocupa esta fórmula, revisa cual de las 2 es la fórmula que necesitas.

```
        //según otra página
        numero = (constante*semilla) % modulo;   
        numero2 = numero / (modulo-1);
        semilla = numero;  


      numeros.push(numero);

      // Insertar fila en la tabla
      var row = table.insertRow();
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(numero));
row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(numero2.toFixed(4)));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Congruencial Multiplicativo</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="semilla">Semilla inicial:</label>
        <input type="text" id="semillas" name="semillas"><br>

        <label for="k">k</label>
        <input type="text" id="k" name="k"><br>

        <label for="g">g:</label>
        <input type="text" id="g" name="g"><br>

        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de números:</label>
        <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" value="10"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="generar()">Generar</button>
    </form>
    <p id="resultado"></p>

    <script>
            function generar() {
  var semilla = parseInt(document.getElementById("semillas").value);
  var constante = parseInt(document.getElementById("k").value);
  var modulo = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);
  var cantidad = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value);

  // Verificar condiciones necesarias
  //esta condición hay que corregirla
/*   if (semilla % 2 !== 0 && (constante === 3 || constante === 5 || constante % 8 === 3 || constante % 8 === 5)) { */
    if (semilla % 2 !== 0 && Number.isInteger(modulo)){
    var numeros = [];
    var x = semilla;

    var numero = semilla;
    var r;

    // Crear tabla
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var headerRow = table.insertRow();
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("i"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("X[i]"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("número generado"));
    headerRow.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode("r"));

    for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
  //      console.log("semilla: ",semilla, " constante: ", constante, " modulo: ", modulo, "cantidad: ", cantidad);
    


        numero = (modulo + 8*constante)*numero % ( Math.pow(2,modulo) );

        r = numero/((  Math.pow(2,modulo) ) - 1)


      numeros.push(numero);

      // Insertar fila en la tabla
      var row = table.insertRow();
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
    //  row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(numero));
      row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(r.toFixed(4)));


      x = numero;
    }

    // Agregar tabla al documento
    var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    resultado.innerHTML = "";
    resultado.appendChild(table);
  } else {
    alert("Los valores ingresados para los parámetros no cumplen las condiciones necesarias para alcanzar el período máximo.");
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano me sirvio demasiado tu ejemplo